# How to move values in a list one by one?

Tags: python, list

I'm learning python, and am trying to move values in a list in loop. But dont know how to do it. So, if I have this:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can i rotate the values to right by one and get 
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
and then move again 
[ 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest why would be to use deque.

```
from collections import deque

d = deque(list1)
d.rotate(1)
print(d)
d.rotate(1)
print(d)
```

Gives:

```
deque(['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
deque(['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use list slice notation:

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> list1[:-1]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list1[-1:]
['d']
>>> list1[-1:] + list1[:-1]
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> def rotate(lst):
...   return lst[-1:] + lst[:-1]
... 
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> list1 = rotate(list1)
>>> list1
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list1 = rotate(list1)
>>> list1
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```